# Knockout bind HTML datepicker min and max

Tags: javascript, html, date, knockout.js

I have two HTML date pickers that I am having trouble with.  What I am trying to do is set the value and apply a minimum and maximum criteria with Knockout.  After much research I found [the proper date format](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) for the proper format for value, min, and maximum.  Trouble is, the min and max does not seem to work.

Here is my HTML date picker:

```
<input type="date" data-bind="value: MinDate, min: MinDateRange, max: MaxDateRange" />
```

The format of all the dates is yyyy-MM-dd in accordance with the link I sent.  If I manually apply the min and max as attributes the date format works just fine.  Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just use `min` and `max` because there is no such bindingHandlers. But you can use attr bindingHandler:

```
<input type="date" data-bind="value: MinDate, attr: { min: MinDateRange, max: MaxDateRange }" />
```

Comment: Thank you!  Duh!!  Now I feel dumb.

Comment: This doesn't re-bind/update if MinDateRange or MaxDateRange  are observables.